# "Laughing our heads off" in Latin

Tags: idiom, english-to-latin-translation, prefix

As a follow-up of an interesting question on a typological classification of Latin ([Are Latin verbs of motion satellite-framed or verb-framed?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/11083/are-latin-verbs-of-motion-satellite-framed-or-verb-framed) ), I was wondering if Latin has (semi)idiomatic expressions like the following ones:

English (satellite-framed language):
*Ben worked his guts out // Ben cried his eyes out // Ben laughed his butt off // Ben laughed his head off // ...*  (meaning: 'Ben Verb-ed a lot').

Spanish (verb-framed language):
*Ben echó los higadillos (de tanto trabajar) // A Ben se le salieron los ojos de tanto llorar // Ben se petó de risa //...*

NB: as you can see, the important satellite- vs. verb-framed typology goes beyond motion verbs.

Assuming that these idiomatic constructions can be found in Latin, the expected pattern should be the following one, with Path/Result prefixed onto the verb, i.e., something like *outwork*, *outcry*, etc.

Unfortunately, so far I've been unable to find idiomatic expressions like *He cried his eyes out* in Latin. Interestingly, this class of idioms is not productive in Slavic languages (which, like Latin, are also "weak satellite-framed languages"; see my answer to the post above) as it is in Germanic languages, but some examples can be found:

a. Jan schodził sobie nogi             (Polish)

Jan out-walked refl-dat feet

‘John walked his feet off.’  (meaning 'he walked a lot')

b. Džon vyplakal svoi glaza            (Russian)

John out-cried  poss. eyes

‘John cried his eyes out.’   (meaning 'he cried a lot').

Comment: In one translation of *deditus* the *de-* implies things have gone awry -held hostage; in the other *de-* is an intensifier, absolutely hooked on. This is another case where vowel length keeps readers on their toes.

Comment: Another candidate, inspired by @Hugh's comment: [delacrimo](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=delacrimo&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059).

Comment: Thanks for the examples & comments on the intensive meaning of prefix _de-_. Yes, a prefixed denominal verb like _delacrimo_ can also mean to cry intensively but in this post I was wondering if (semi)idiomatic verbal phrases like "prefix-activity verb + direct object (body part)" are possible in Latin, i.e., examples where the verbal root expresses an activity (e.g., crying), the prefix expresses a Path/Result (e.g., out) and the direct object is a body part or related entity: e.g., cf. the Russian example at the end of my question .